# assign kubernetes loadbalancer an ip from an internal network

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I am having an aks instance running. which I assigned an virtual network to it. So all the Node IPs in the network are good and I can reach them from within the network.

Now I wonder if it is possible to create a 2nd virtual network and tell kubernetes to use it to assign public ips ?

Or maybe is it possible to say that a specific service should always have the same node ip ?

Comment: What do you want to create a 2nd virtual network? Access from the other Vnet or Internet?

Comment: I need to find a solution for the staging environment, where I am having a kubernetes cluster, which is having a load balancer, but is not exposed to the public

Comment: AKS cluster actually acts as a resource group that named MC_resourcegroupName_AKSClusterName_location. So if you want to expose the load balancer which existed to a public IP, you can find the AKS resource group and create a public IP associated to the load balancer so that you can expose the load balancer to the public.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not supported, you might be able to hack your way through, but certainly not out of the box.

But you can create an internal load balancer for your service in the network and its ip wouldnt change, you do this using a service with an annotation:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: name
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
spec:
  ports:
  - port: xxx
  selector:
    app: name
  type: LoadBalancer
```